# How to make efficient data retrieval avoiding repetitions in Mvc Actionreult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my action and I have a strongly typed view with almost 10+ dropdowns. Now situation is for edit and listing and new in all cases I have to provide value to viewmodel. I need suggestions about how I can avoid such repetition

```
public ActionResult Employees()
{
    if (!ISValidLogin())
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

    EmployeeViewModel objEmpViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel();
    objEmpViewModel.GetCampusByClientId = objGlobalRepo.GetCampusByClientId(Convert.ToInt32(Encrypt.GetUserCookieValue("ClientID")));
    objEmpViewModel.GetBloodGroups = objGlobalRepo.GetBloodGroups();
    objEmpViewModel.GetCategories = objGlobalRepo.GetCategoriesList();
    objEmpViewModel.GetNationalities = objGlobalRepo.GetNationalities();
    objEmpViewModel.GetOccupation = objGlobalRepo.GetOccupation();
    objEmpViewModel.GetQualificationTypes = objGlobalRepo.GetQualificationTypes();
    objEmpViewModel.GetRelation = objGlobalRepo.GetRelation();
    objEmpViewModel.GetReligionsList = objGlobalRepo.GetReligionsList();
    objEmpViewModel.GetCountries = objGlobalRepo.GetCountries();
    objEmpViewModel.GetDepartments = objGlobalRepo.GetDepartments();
    objEmpViewModel.GetDesignation = objGlobalRepo.GetDesignations();
    objEmpViewModel.GetMaritalStatus = objGlobalRepo.GetMaritalStatus();
    objEmpViewModel.GetRanks = objGlobalRepo.GetRanks();
    objEmpViewModel.GetSpecialization = objGlobalRepo.GetSpecialization();
    objEmpViewModel.GetTitlesList = objGlobalRepo.GetTitles();
    objEmpViewModel.EmployeeInfo = new Employee();
    objEmpViewModel.EmployeeList = objEmployeeRepo.EmployeeList();
    objEmpViewModel.GuradiansDetails = new List<Guardian>();
    objEmpViewModel.GuradiansDetails.Add(new Guardian());
    objEmpViewModel.GetGender = objGlobalRepo.GetGender();
    objEmpViewModel.GetEmployeeCategoriesList = objGlobalRepo.GetEmployeeCategoriesList();

    ViewBag.Message = Convert.ToString(TempData["message"]);

    TempData.Remove("message");

    return View(objEmpViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Employees(EmployeeViewModel objEmpViewModel,HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        string filename = FileUploads.SaveFile(file, Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Employee/"));
        objEmpViewModel.EmployeeInfo.ImageUrl = filename;
    }

    string result = objEmployeeRepo.AddEmployee(objEmpViewModel.EmployeeInfo, objEmpViewModel.GuradiansDetails);

    objEmpViewModel.GetCampusByClientId = objGlobalRepo.GetCampusByClientId(Convert.ToInt32(Encrypt.GetUserCookieValue("ClientID")));
    objEmpViewModel.GetBloodGroups = objGlobalRepo.GetBloodGroups();
    objEmpViewModel.GetCategories = objGlobalRepo.GetCategoriesList();
    objEmpViewModel.GetNationalities = objGlobalRepo.GetNationalities();
    objEmpViewModel.GetOccupation = objGlobalRepo.GetOccupation();
    objEmpViewModel.GetQualificationTypes = objGlobalRepo.GetQualificationTypes();
    objEmpViewModel.GetRelation = objGlobalRepo.GetRelation();
    objEmpViewModel.GetReligionsList = objGlobalRepo.GetReligionsList();
    objEmpViewModel.GetCountries = objGlobalRepo.GetCountries();
    objEmpViewModel.GetDepartments = objGlobalRepo.GetDepartments();
    objEmpViewModel.GetDesignation = objGlobalRepo.GetDesignations();
    objEmpViewModel.GetMaritalStatus = objGlobalRepo.GetMaritalStatus();
    objEmpViewModel.GetRanks = objGlobalRepo.GetRanks();
    objEmpViewModel.GetSpecialization = objGlobalRepo.GetSpecialization();
    objEmpViewModel.GetTitlesList = objGlobalRepo.GetTitles();
    objEmpViewModel.EmployeeList = objEmployeeRepo.EmployeeList();
    objEmpViewModel.EmployeeInfo = new Employee();
    objEmpViewModel.GuradiansDetails = new List<Guardian>();
    objEmpViewModel.GuradiansDetails.Add(new Guardian());
    objEmpViewModel.GetGender = objGlobalRepo.GetGender();
    objEmpViewModel.GetEmployeeCategoriesList = objGlobalRepo.GetEmployeeCategoriesList();

    TempData["message"] = "<div class='alert alert-success alert - dismissible fade in' role='alert'> <button type = 'button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span>  </button> <strong>" + result + "</strong>  </div>";

    return View(objEmpViewModel);
}
```

So these two methods have same line for populating properties. Basically I don't want to write those lines again and again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "avoiding repetitions"? Not duplicating code? Not duplicating data? Not having to call the same methods each time? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: have a look again .Those two actions have same lines to assign data to viewmodel properties.That repetition is what i wanna avoid

Comment: Well, you know how to write methods. Why don't you write a method that returns you the object filled?

Comment: Write a method that sets up the EmployeeViewModel and possibly use a cache.

Comment: i did that just five minutes ago.I mean creating method.I was just curious if there is something better than just that.something that i might now have knowledge about.

Comment: earlier i tried to make those database calls directly on properties get method.Thats was working fine just didn't know if that a right way

Comment: As others have mentioned, create a helper method in that controller class that creates and returns the model you need, complete with all the collections you're currently putting into it.  A bigger concern from my perspective, though, is all the repetitive one-off trips to the database to retrieve those collections.  If the lists are stable/static, then I would cache them `HttpContext.Current.Cache`. Lastly, why are you prefixing all of your objects with `obj`?  Hungarian notation died 20 years ago.  Go ahead and just call your model "model". `EmployeeViewModel model = new EmployeeViewModel();`